# How can add fade In() effect to each appearance of a div when the mouse click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

How can add `fadeIn()` effect to each appearance of a div  when the mouse click?

So when onmouseclick, yellow part is showing with `fadeIn()` effect.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2ehdW/7/

Script :

```
window.jQueryclick: function (event) {
    if (!event.point.selected) {
        $('#testDiv').show();
        var chart_data = '<div> Name: ' + event.point.name + ' Share: ' + event.point.y + '</div>';
        $('#testDiv').html(chart_data);
    } else {
        $('#testDiv').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the circle's sector that highlights yellow and expands when selected to fade in, or do you want the div that states "Name: _browser_name_ share: " to fade in?

Comment: The div that states "Name: browser_name share: " to fade in - this is what I want.

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem is, you can use fadeIn instead of show() like here http://jsfiddle.net/2ehdW/18/ so could you explain what is wrong ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan as far as I understood, the problem is that on further clicks div does not fade.

Comment: Well, it is ok for me, as I toggle many times.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add a parameter to `.show()` method and hide the `div` before showing it again:

```
if (!event.point.selected) {
   $('#testDiv').hide();
   $('#testDiv').show("300"); //or just $('#testDiv').fadeIn();
   var chart_data = 'Name: ' + event.point.name + ' Share: ' + event.point.y;
   $('#testDiv').html(chart_data);
} else {
   $('#testDiv').hide();
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2ehdW/9/)